# How to get values from the custom Select component?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm having some trouble getting the submitted values from the `Select` component imported from `react-select`. The `FormData` object doesn't know how to read them and they're not accessible through `event.target.values`. Does anyone know how to read these values? (sample component within the form listed below)

```js
function ClassType() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.classType}>
      <span>Give me a</span>
      <Select className={styles.select} options={GEN_ED_CLASSES} instanceId />
      <span>class</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can't you use `onChange` event on `Select`? It would be great if you share a sandbox that contains your issue

Comment: I could use `onChange` but it's only necessary to update state when the form is submitted and I wanted to avoid unnecessary re-renders. My `Select` component is within a form and I simply want to extract its value at the time the form is submitted. I tried using `onSubmit` but its the form being submitted not the `Select` component.